# In web-mode PHP block in HTML file doesn't syntax highlight

Tags: web-mode

I'm a emacs beginner, hope this not a stupid question.

Here is the issue: when I open a html file that contains php block, every html thing got correct syntax highlight, but the php block. The web-mode version is 12.2.10, and emacs is 24.5.1. And when I open a php file contains html codes, everything works fine.

The following is my web-mode configuration:

```
(require 'web-mode)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.phtml\\'" . web-mode))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\.php\\'" . web-mode))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[agj]sp\\'" . web-mode))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.as[cp]x\\'" . web-mode))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.erb\\'" . web-mode))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mustache\\'" . web-mode))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.djhtml\\'" . web-mode))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html?\\'" . web-mode))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html$" . web-mode))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . web-mode))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php$" . web-mode))

(setq web-mode-engines-alist
      '(("php"    . "\\.phtml\\'")
        ("blade"  . "\\.blade\\.")))
```

[image]

What else should I do to make this right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `(setq web-mode-engines-alist '(("php" . "\\.html\\'")))` in your `.emacs`. Indeed, web-mode.el can not guess the template engine with such a generic extension. You can find more informations about `web-mode-engines-alist` on http://web-mode.org

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario 1:** You are editing your own files.

In this case, and if possible, it's better to identify the kind of HTML file you are editing by a unique extension: .djhtml for django files, etc.

**Scenario 2:** You are editing your own files, but for some reason you are obliged to use the generic .html extension.

Add a comment to your .html file:

```
<?php /* -*- engine:php -*- */ ?>
```

**Scenario 3:** You are editing (or just browsing) someone else's files.

So now you are unable to change the file extension or to introduce a comment line in each file.

In that case add

```
(setq web-mode-engines-alist '(("php" . "\\.html\\'")))
```

to your .emacs, but beware that you are now in "php-only mode", in the sense that if you view/edit a .html file that contains, say, django markups, it will still be interpreted as php.