# web-mode didn't work properly under Emacs

Tags: html, web-mode

I am using Emacs 25.3.1 under MS Windows 64-bit, Everything seems working fine except the `web-mode`. If I try to edit an HTML file there is no syntax highlighting, when mixing PHP and HTML only the PHP code fragments are colored, the HTML parts are in black/gray color scheme.
My `.emacs` file looks like this under `(package-initialize)`:

```
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.phtml\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html?\\'" . web-mode))

(setq web-mode-engines-alist '(("php" . "\\.html\\'")))
```

The last line was added, as it was required by [fxbois](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17010/in-web-mode-php-block-in-html-file-doesnt-syntax-highlight), but it doesn't solve the issue.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `web-mode-enable-element-content-fontification`. There are many more options for `web-mode`. Try `M-x customize-group RET web-mode RET`.